# how to use python to check whether the system setting for mouse is left-handed?

Tags: python, automation, mouse

### Motivation

I'm going to use python to click the left mouse button to do some automation test.

### My development & test environment

- My local development machine(Win10) is left-handed for mouse. It means that I click the left button of my mouse to show the Mouse-Right-Click-Menu.
- The test server is right-handed for mouse. I usually use TeamViewer to access the test server, and I don't need additional settings for mouse on the test server for my access. I mean, with TeamViewer, if I click left button of my mouse in the TeamViewer viewport, the Mouse-Right-Click-Menu is popped up on the test server.

### Problem

- I use pynput(https://pypi.org/project/pynput/) to click the mouse button. Here is a test code:

  ```
  def simulate_left_click():

      from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
      m = Controller()
      m.press(Button.right)
  ```

On my local machine which is left-handed, this code does NOT pop Mouse-Right-Click-Menu, which is what I want, while on test server which is right-handed, this code pops Mouse-Right-Click-Menu. This inconsistent behavior of this code is annoying.

### What I want to do

I want to write a function 'is_system_left_handed()', like this:

```
def simulate_left_click():
    from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
    m = Controller()
    if is_system_left_handed():
        m.press(Button.right)
    else:
        m.press(Button.left)
```

### My questions

- How to implement the function 'is_system_left_handed()'? is it possible?
- If it is not possible, is there any other python package available for this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use [GetSystemMetrics(SM_SWAPBUTTON)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385(v=vs.85).aspx) to detect if the Mouse-Buttons are swapped...

```
SM_SWAPBUTTON = 23
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics
print(GetSystemMetrics(SM_SWAPBUTTON))
```

PS: 
Requires pywin32:  `python -m pip install pywin32`

Comment: Thank your for your reply. Should I use 'python -m pip install pypiwin32' rather than 'python -m pip install pywin32'?

Comment: @yaoyansi - Good question, I didn't even know about pypiwin32. Both should work. Use whatever floats your boat.